# HTML site image background showing error on iPhone

Tags: android, html, css, iphone

I build a html website showing on my mobile device, while there's no problem showing image background on my Android device Galaxy S4 like this(The profile is showing!) [image], on the other hand, the profile background is not showing correctly  like this [image]. I had adjust the *background-size* so on, but all is vain. So this is my CSS code below:

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 640px) {

.hrader-part{

```
    background: url(../images/bg_android.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px
    }

    }
```

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1080px) {

.hrader-part{

```
    background: url(../images/bg_android.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    width: 365px;
    height: 100%
    }

    }
```

Thanks a lot buddies!

Answer (score 1):

I do not have access to an iPhone, but I was able to reproduce your bug in Safari 7 on Mac OS X, using the iPhone user agent. The css from the media query was not being applied to the element. Changing `max-device-width` to `max-width` fixed the problem.

Also regarding your media queries: The `max-device-width: 1080px` query overrides the`max-device-width: 640px` query, since it comes later in the stylesheet. If you add a `min-width` attribute to the second media query, it will allow both queries to function:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 1080px)
```

Comment: hi, I had tried your suggestion, but it didn't work, and I worked whole day through, it was finally fixed by changing background-attachment: fixed; to background-attachment: scroll. Thank you for your kindly help anyway!